# Hiding/deleting elf symbols using visbility or linker, without shared library

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I would like to hide some symbols from normal usage from a C library/file to prevent name clashes and to avoid possible expansion of the API ([Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/)).  Static symbols are hidden (but my use case is multi-file, so I cannot use them).  Visibility kinda works--but apparently only if you are using a shared library (not possible for my use case).

I've tried using version linker scripts to hide all symbols except the one I want to expose, but it doesn't seem to actually affect the link (even when subsequently turning it into a shared library).

--function-sections will not help--the functions are used internally.  -fwhole-program might work, if it was not hardwired to only expose main.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

cat > foo.c <<EOF
extern void exportfunc_nonattr(void);
extern void exportfunc_default(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")));
extern void exportfunc_internal(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("internal")));
extern void exportfunc_hidden(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
extern void exportfunc_protected(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("protected")));
void func_nonattr(void);
void func_default(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")));
void func_internal(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("internal")));
void func_hidden(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
void func_protected(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("protected")));
static void staticfunc(void);

void exportfunc_nonattr(void) {}
void exportfunc_default(void) {}
void exportfunc_internal(void) {}
void exportfunc_hidden(void) {}
void exportfunc_protected(void) {}
void func_nonattr(void) {}
void func_default(void) {}
void func_internal(void) {}
void func_hidden(void) {}
void func_protected(void) {}
void staticfunc(void) {}
EOF
cat > food.c <<EOF
extern void exportfunc_nonattr(void);
extern void exportfunc_default(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")));
extern void exportfunc_internal(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("internal")));
extern void exportfunc_hidden(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
extern void exportfunc_protected(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("protected")));
void func_nonattr(void);
void func_default(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")));
void func_internal(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("internal")));
void func_hidden(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
void func_protected(void) __attribute__ ((visibility ("protected")));
#ifdef TRY_STATIC
static void staticfunc(void);
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    exportfunc_nonattr();
    exportfunc_default();
    exportfunc_internal();
    exportfunc_hidden();
    exportfunc_protected();
    func_nonattr();
    func_default();
    func_internal();
    func_hidden();
    func_protected();
#ifdef TRY_STATIC
    staticfunc();
#endif
}
EOF
cat > foo.script <<EOF
{
  global:
    exportfunc_default;
  local:
    *;
};
EOF

: Compile test source
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -fvisibility=internal -c -o foo-internal.o foo.c

# Try different ways to permute the produced object files (with and without internal visibility): shared library, garbage collection, linker scripts
for f in foo foo-internal; do
  : === Direct link $f
  gcc -o foo-exec food.c $f.o
  : === Linker Script $f
  ld -O3 -i --version-script foo.script -o $f-script.o $f.o
  gcc -o foo-exec food.c ./$f-script.o && ./foo-exec
  : === Garbage collected linker script $f
  ld -O3 -x -i --gc-sections -e exportfunc_default --version-script foo.script -o $f-gcscript.o $f.o
  gcc -o foo-exec food.c ./$f-gcscript.o && ./foo-exec
done
```

As a gift for those who actually do want shared libraries, the following commands (if inserted in the above shell script inside the loop) will fail links with "undefined references" for the hidden, protected, and internal symbols.  If compiled with -fvisibility, the nonattr variants are undefined as well.

```
  echo === Shared library
  gcc -shared -o lib$f.so $f.o
  gcc -o foo-exec food.c -L. -l$f && ./foo-exec
  echo  === Garbage collected shared library
  gcc -Wl,--gc-sections -shared -o lib$f-gc.so $f.o
  gcc -o foo-exec food.c -L. -l$f-gc && ./foo-exec
```